# Is there a MySQL % (approximation) equivalent in VBA?

Tags: mysql, vba, if-statement, search, approximate

I want a VBA to look through a cell and determine whether the word `XXX` appears anywhere in it using the `%`. If yes I want VBA to change the entire cell to the word `YYY`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change only 1 cell's value, then use the InStr() function:

```vb
If InStr(1, Cells(1, 1).Value, "xxx")>0 Then Cells(1, 1).Value="xxx"
```

Obviously, replace `Cells(1, 1).Value` with your cell reference.

If you need to check multiple cells, then use the [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method:

```vb
Dim firstAddress As String
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 
    Set c = .Find("xxx", lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
            c.Value = "xxx" 
            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
    End If 
End With
```

Again, replace `Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500")` with your own range reference.

Comment: Thanks. I need a single cell so the first piece of code works. What can I do to make VBA spit out a different value if the cell =/= XXX? I tried "Else" and  it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Else should work, but I cannot possibly know what went wrong with your code, when you only tell that "it does not seem to work".

Comment: Oh.. sorry, I must have made a mistake. I doublechecked and it works now. Thank you, my question is answered.

Comment: Perhaps you could mark the answer as accepted then to indicate other readers that the question has already been answered.

Comment: Sure thing. Thank you again.